# bottom Sheet Dialog Crashing

Tags: java, android, firebase, crash, android-debug

```
 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //handle item clicks show item details (in bottom sheet)
             detailBottomProduct(productModel); 

        }
    });
```

private void detailBottomProduct(ProductModel productModel) {
final BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(context);
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.bs_product_details_seller,null);

```
    //init View

   

    ImageView productIconIv =  view.findViewById(R.id.productIconIv);

    TextView discountNoteTv =  view.findViewById(R.id.discountNoteTv);
    TextView titleTv =  view.findViewById(R.id.titleTv);
    TextView descriptionTv =  view.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTv);
    TextView categoryTv =  view.findViewById(R.id.categoryTv);
    TextView quantityTv =  view.findViewById(R.id.quantityTv);
    TextView discountPriceTv =  view.findViewById(R.id.discountPriceTv);
    TextView priceTv =  view.findViewById(R.id.priceTv);

    //get Data
    final String id = productModel.getProductId();
    String uid = productModel.getUid();
    String discountAvailable = productModel.getDiscountAvailable();
    String discountNote = productModel.getDiscountNote();
    String discountPrice = productModel.getDiscountPrice();
    String productCategory = productModel.getProductCategory();
    String productIcon = productModel.getProductIcon();
    final String title = productModel.getProductTitle();
    String description = productModel.getProductDescription();
    String productQuantity = productModel.getProductQuantity();
    String timestamp = productModel.getTimestamp();
    String actualPrice = productModel.getProductPrice();

    //setData
    titleTv.setText(title);
    descriptionTv.setText(description);
    categoryTv.setText(productCategory);
    priceTv.setText("₹ "+ actualPrice);
    quantityTv.setText(productQuantity);
    discountPriceTv.setText("₹ "+discountPrice);
    discountNoteTv.setText(discountNote);

    if (discountAvailable.equals("true")){
        //product is on discount
        discountPriceTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        discountNoteTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        priceTv.setPaintFlags(priceTv.getPaintFlags()| Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    }
    else {
        //product is not on discount
        discountPriceTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        discountNoteTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    try {
        Glide.with(context).load(productIcon).into(productIconIv);

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        productIconIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_shopping_primary);
    }

    //set view
    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(view);

    //show dialog
    bottomSheetDialog.show();  // app crashed point (Line 173 )
}
```

Complete Adapter Code:

```
public class AdapterProductSeller extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterProductSeller.HolderProductSeller> 
implements Filterable {
private Context context;
public ArrayList<ProductModel> productList,filterList;
private FilterProduct filter;

public AdapterProductSeller(Context context, ArrayList<ProductModel> productList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.productList = productList;
    this.filterList = productList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public HolderProductSeller onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //inflate  layout
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_product_seller,parent,false);
    return new HolderProductSeller(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HolderProductSeller holder, int position) {
    //getData
    ProductModel productModel = productList.get(position);
    String id = productModel.getProductId();
    String uid = productModel.getUid();
    String discountAvailable = productModel.getDiscountAvailable();
    String discountNote = productModel.getDiscountNote();
    String discountPrice = productModel.getDiscountPrice();
    String productCategory = productModel.getProductCategory();
    String productIcon = productModel.getProductIcon();
    String title = productModel.getProductTitle();
    String description = productModel.getProductDescription();
    String productQuantity = productModel.getProductQuantity();
    String timestamp = productModel.getTimestamp();
    String actualPrice = productModel.getProductPrice();

    //setData
    holder.discountNoteTv.setText(discountNote);
    holder.titleTv.setText(title);
    holder.quantityTv.setText(productQuantity);
    holder.discountPriceTv.setText("₹"+discountPrice);
    if (discountAvailable.equals("true")){
        //product is on discount
        holder.discountPriceTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.discountNoteTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.priceTv.setPaintFlags(holder.priceTv.getPaintFlags()| Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    }
    else {
        //product is not on discount
        holder.discountPriceTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.discountNoteTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    try {
        Glide.with(context).load(productIcon).into(holder.productIconIv);

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        holder.productIconIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_shopping_primary);
    }
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //handle item clicks show item details (in bottom sheet)
                detailBottomProduct(productModel);

        }
    });
}

private void detailBottomProduct(ProductModel productModel) {
   final BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(context);
   View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.bs_product_details_seller,null);

    //init View

    ImageButton backBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.backBtn);
    ImageButton editBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.editBtn);
    ImageButton deleteBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);

    ImageView productIconIv =  view.findViewById(R.id.productIconIv);

    TextView discountNoteTv =  view.findViewById(R.id.discountNoteTv);
    TextView titleTv =  view.findViewById(R.id.titleTv);
    TextView descriptionTv =  view.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTv);
    TextView categoryTv =  view.findViewById(R.id.categoryTv);
    TextView quantityTv =  view.findViewById(R.id.quantityTv);
    TextView discountPriceTv =  view.findViewById(R.id.discountPriceTv);
    TextView priceTv =  view.findViewById(R.id.priceTv);

    //get Data
    final String id = productModel.getProductId();
    String uid = productModel.getUid();
    String discountAvailable = productModel.getDiscountAvailable();
    String discountNote = productModel.getDiscountNote();
    String discountPrice = productModel.getDiscountPrice();
    String productCategory = productModel.getProductCategory();
    String productIcon = productModel.getProductIcon();
    final String title = productModel.getProductTitle();
    String description = productModel.getProductDescription();
    String productQuantity = productModel.getProductQuantity();
    String timestamp = productModel.getTimestamp();
    String actualPrice = productModel.getProductPrice();

    //setData
    titleTv.setText(title);
    descriptionTv.setText(description);
    categoryTv.setText(productCategory);
    priceTv.setText("₹ "+ actualPrice);
    quantityTv.setText(productQuantity);
    discountPriceTv.setText("₹ "+discountPrice);
    discountNoteTv.setText(discountNote);

    if (discountAvailable.equals("true")){
        //product is on discount
        discountPriceTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        discountNoteTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        priceTv.setPaintFlags(priceTv.getPaintFlags()| Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    }
    else {
        //product is not on discount
        discountPriceTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        discountNoteTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    try {
        Glide.with(context).load(productIcon).into(productIconIv);

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        productIconIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_shopping_primary);
    }

    //set view
    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(view);

    //show dialog
    bottomSheetDialog.show();
    // edit click
    editBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
            //open product activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, EditProductActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("productId",id);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    //delete Btn
    deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
           //show delete confirm dialog
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle("Delete")
                    .setMessage("Are  you sure you want to delete product"+title+"?")
                    .setPositiveButton("DELETE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //delete
                    deleteProduct(id);

                }
            }).setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //cancel dialog dismiss
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            })
            .show();

        }
    });
    //back  btn
    backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //dismiss bottom sheet
            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });


}

private void deleteProduct(String id) {
    //delete product with string id
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Sellers");
    reference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("products").child(id).removeValue()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Product Deleted...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    //failed  deleting product
                    Toast.makeText(context, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productList.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (filter == null){
        filter = new FilterProduct(this,filterList);
    }
    return filter;
}

class HolderProductSeller extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    /* holds view of  recycler view */

    private ImageView productIconIv,nextIv;
    private TextView discountNoteTv,titleTv,quantityTv,
    discountPriceTv,priceTv;


    public HolderProductSeller(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        productIconIv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productIconIv);
        nextIv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nextIv);
        discountNoteTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.discountNoteTv);
        titleTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTv);
        quantityTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantityTv);
        quantityTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantityTv);
        discountPriceTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.discountPriceTv);
        priceTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceTv);
    }

}
```

}

When I clicked any items in the app[Firebase showing the  crashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F715p.jpg) closed an exception error occurs[Logcat showing Crashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ux9H.png)

Comment: I want to click on item view so it shows the data at that position in modal class but when I clicked app crash happing. and it happens when I called bottomsheetdialog.show(); in code

Comment: Your `context` is null. Please check right context is passing to dialog?

Comment: paste error text

Comment: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException
Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
com.business.groceryapp.adapter.AdapterProductSeller.detailBottomProduct

Comment: How can I check that context is null or not  because the product list  is present in recycler view and I passed that context

Comment: please format your question!